# Xbox One Grand Theft Auto V save transfer to xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

I bought Grand Theft Auto 5 for the Xbox One, but never for the Xbox 360.

If I now buy it on the Xbox 360, will my account already have all of its progress?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The Xbox One and Xbox 360 consoles use differant save states for the game, and as such, your save file would be completely incompatible.

Furthermore, the save transfer feature offered by Rockstar is exclusively for converting from Xbox 360 to Xbox One, not the other way around.

Comment: @steven, if this answers your question, be sure to accept it by clicking on the tick icon, to let other users know that this answer solved your problem.